# When clicking on the "Traditional view" button there is an extra line break and a poor text arrangement

Tags: bug, developer-story, user-interface, user-experience, traditional-view

The story view pressed button looks like:

> [image]

And that's OK. But when I click on Traditional view, the view switcher widget gets broken or looks inconsistent:

> [image]

The problems:

1. There is an extra line break between "Traditional view" and "Story view" buttons. Even on 20"+ Full HD screens.
2. The text and link "Visibility: Private Update privacy" is poorly arranged, extra line break and upper padding/margin issues for the "Visibility: Private" text.

It should look like it is when the story view button is pressed.

Comment: Traditionally, resumes and CVs have been poorly formatted. Are you sure it's a bug? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the bug has been fixed:

[image]
[image]